# Can we register Continuous Query notification with java implementation ?If Yes, then how?

Tags: java, oracle12c

In oracle 11g, it is possible to register query with java implementation but in oracle 12c, I am not getting any option .

If it is not possible by oracle 12c, then what all impediment will be there ?

Comment: In Oracle [12.1.0.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/READM/chapter12101.htm#READM329) and [12.1.0.2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/READM/chapter12102.htm#READM119) CQN is not supported. But, if you have the option for upgrading to [12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/continuos-query-notification.html#GUID-4987516F-872F-47D1-B9E7-270A28D50AF8) it supports CQN.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Is there any difference between CQN and DCN?
As i can see same things explained in oracle 11g and in Oracle 12c(12.2) .I am new to this, so bit confused.Can you please help me in understanding the both concept? Thanks in advance:):) @learningloop